# Converting row and column values to indexes for multiple arrays with grouped values

Tags: arrays, math

This kind of question pops up on SO a lot, but bear with me, it has a twist.

Let's say you have the following array...

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H , I, J, K, L]
```

Which you map to a grid like this

```
 | 0 1 2 3
 ----------
0| A D G J
1| B E H K
2| C F I L
```

If you need to find the original array index for any item in the grid, you can use this formula (rows and cols are zero based).

```
col * numRows + row
```

So the index for 'I', which sits at coords `2,2` on the grid would be...

```
2 * 3 + 2 = 8
```

Simples! So now imagine you have two arrays...

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H , I, J, K, L]
[@, &, *, #, €, %, ƒ, œ, ≈, ∑, ß, Ω ]
```

Which is laid out in a grid like this...

```
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
 -----------------
0| A @ D # G ƒ J ∑
1| B & E € H œ K ß
2| C * F % I ≈ L Ω
```

Now you need to constrain the column indexes so that 0 & 1 = 0, 2 & 3 = 1 etc etc. For that, I've come up with this formula.

```
Math.floor(column / numArrays) * numRows + row;
```

Now let's turn it up a gear. Imagine you have these two arrays (16 items in each)

```
[1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8]
[100,100,200,200,300,300,400,400,500,500,600,600,700,700,800,800]
```

But now, you want the grid to display rows where pairs of values have been summed

```
   0 1   2  3
----------------
0| 2 200 10 1000 
1| 4 400 12 1200
2| 6 600 14 1400
3| 8 800 16 1600
```

And you want to find the first index in the original array, e.g. the index for the value 8, would be 15, or the index for value 400 would be 2.

I'd made the naive assumption that you could just multiply the row and column indexes by the `chunk size` I'm was using to sum the values. That is however, completely wrong.

So, is it possible to derive the index in a flat array using row and column indexes when the grid is composed of multiple arrays whose values have been interleaved, AND summed (or as I call it, 'collapsed')?

UPDATE: I've made a little bit of progress. If my second formula was the function

```
func coordsToIndex(col, row, totalDataSets, totalRows) {
  return Math.floor(col / totalDataSets) * totalRows + row;
}
```

And if the variable `chunkSize` indicates how many values are being summed together, then this

```
coordsToIndex(col, row, totalDataSets, totalRows) * chunkSize
```

Comes close, but the resulting index is always too large by the chunk size. SO!

```
(coordsToIndex(col, row, totalDataSets, totalRows) * chunkSize) - chunkSize
```

Gives me the correct value, BUT only when the chunkSize is greater than zero, which leads me to...

```
index = (coordsToIndex(col, row, totalDataSets, totalRows) * chunkSize)
realIndex = chunkSize > 1 
  ? (index * chunkSize) - chunkSize 
  : calculatedIndex;
```

I sense that there's a neater way to do this and that I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

Comment: So when in the above example column with even number has sum of elements from array 1 and odd columns have sum of elements from array 2. So, your question is basically in the above scenario how we will form the original array back but each cell is sum of two numbers, how can we split into two integers without knowing one value ?

Comment: Not quite. I don't need to recreate the original array. I'm keeping that around. What I need to do is take the row and column indexes, and figure out what the index in the original array would be for those coordinates. And in the case where the values have been summed, I need to find the first index of the first value used in the sum. 

I hope that makes sense. It's difficult to articulate the problem.